# Rails nested form error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have no idea what could possibly be causing this.  I am making my second nested form in an app.  I have a website for students to get jobs.  The Job model and form refers to work done off of the site  and simply lists a student's real world jobs.  It is a nested form and is part of a model called Resume.  I have another model, completely different, called Schedule.  Schedule belongs_to a model called Project.  I am trying to make a nested form so a user can create a schedule.  Both forms use javascript to dynamically make new forms on the page as needed.  For some reason, when I try to go to the page with the schedule form, I am told:

```
Missing partial schedules/job_fields, application/job_fields
```

This makes no sense as jobs and schedules have no relationship whatsoever.  It shouldn't be looking for a jobs field partial.  Here is view code for the schedule form:

```
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= form_for project do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :schedules do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'schedule_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Schedule", f, :schedules %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Here is the partial '_schedule_fields.html.erb'

```
<p class = "fieldo">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br />

    <%= f.label :task %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :task %><br />

    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"  %>
 </p>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
//Dynamic forms
 function remove_fields(link) {
         $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
         $(link).closest(".fieldo").hide();
 }

 function add_fields(link, association, content) {
         var new_id = new Date().getTime();
         var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
         $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
 }
```

Now here's something interesting.  If I make a file '_job_fields.html.erb' in the views/schedules directory and copy and paste the content from '_schedule_fields.html.erb', the form works perfectly.  I can't figure out why it is searching for a job_fields partial when i explicitly say in the form schedules. How do I get this working with the schedule_fields partial? Thanks!

Comment: On top of your issue, am I right to assume you're trying to dynamically add fields to this form?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially, each schedule consists of one task.  Each time someone clicks 'add', a new schedule form is dynamically created (one field for title and one field for task)

Comment: Yep, I thought I could recognize what you're doing because I was literally working on this yesterday! There's a really good tutorial (with working demo) here if you need some inspiration: http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not lining up arguments correctly. (If you're using anything in your application helper, you should give that too.)

Your link_to function looks like this

```
link_to_add_fields "Add Schedule", f, :schedules
```

but your javascript is calling for different parameters:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content)
```

If you match them up, you're getting f = association, which is wrong. :schedules is the association. I'd check out this railscast for more help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms